# Getting the number and names of windows in Xvfb

Tags: linux, xorg

I am currently working with Xvfb to grab the screenshots of my programs. Is there a way to determine the number and the names of the windows that are currently "displayed" in Xvfb?

Where can I find more documentation on this?

Answer (score 3):

If you run a window manager on the Xvfb display, you can use whatever features it has to list window information.

On the command line, [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) can show some window information.

```
DISPLAY=:1 wmctrl -l
```

Answer (score 2):

`xwininfo -root -tree`

See [the xwininfo man page](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xwininfo.1.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a very useful information. Do you know a way to get these information in C/C++ (without parsing the command outputs) ?

Comment: You could call XQueryTree yourself, as the older versions of xwininfo do, or the xcb equivalents as the new versions do.

Comment: Do you think it is an advantage to use xcb? As far as I read it's a low level access to the X11 protocol. Also, the API doesn't look as comfortable as using the X11 libs.

Comment: Well, I did when I modified xwininfo to use xcb, but that was as much to serve as an xcb example & test code as for the actual benefits.  http://blogs.sun.com/alanc/entry/porting_xwininfo_to_xcb has a much longer explanation than I can provide here.